# Openwrt: vsftpd file upload

Tags: ftp, openwrt

I am using vsftpd daemon for ftp server and configured the server for local users listed in /etc/vsftpd.users. 
Using filezilla for ftp client and I am getting "553: could not write file" error when I try to upload the file.

vsftpd.conf file is as follows:

```
background=YES
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/mnt/
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
chroot_local_user=YES
chown_uploads=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
check_shell=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
#dirmessage_enable=YES
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
session_support=YES
syslog_enable=YES
#userlist_enable=YES
#userlist_deny=NO
#userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.users
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#xferlog_std_format=YES
###
### TLS/SSL options
### example key generation: openssl req -x509 
#ssl_enable=YES
#allow_anon_ssl=NO
#force_local_data_ssl=NO
#force_local_logins_ssl=NO
#ssl_tlsv1=YES
#ssl_sslv2=NO
#ssl_sslv3=NO
#rsa_cert_file=/etc/config/vsftpd_cert.pem
#rsa_private_key_file=/etc/config/vsftpd_privkey.pem
```

Can anyone tell me , do I have to configure for ftp upload for local users?

Regards,
Sowmya

Comment: 3 things to debug: check for useful error messages in `/var/log/vsftpd.log`, check if the user file-system permissions are correct and confirm you have [configured your firewall correctly for the FTP](http://serverfault.com/a/696184).

Comment: And your combination of `userlist*` directives requires users to be listed in `/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users` to be allowed FTP access, if I read things correctly.

Comment: Please post relevant log messages, as reported via the [logread](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/log.essentials) command. Also, tell us the content of `/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users` and the username you are connecting with, from your FileZilla. Let us also know what do you have under `/mnt`: an external USB flash disk? other? nothing?

Comment: @HBruijn : I doubt `/var/log/vsftpd.log` exists, as we're on an [OpenWRT](http://www.openwrt.org) box and logging, here, is handled differently ( http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/log.essentials) with respect to common GNU/Linux systems

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli: appears to be explcitely configured with `xferlog_enable=YES` & 
`xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log` ...

Comment: @HBruijn : Ops! Sorry! I wrongly defaulted to SYSLOG logging (`syslog_enable=yes`), without considering the explicit configuration you mentioned. BTW: I wonder if `syslog_enable=YES` prevents `xferlog_enable` behaviour (syslog_enable — When enabled in conjunction with xferlog_enable, all logging normally written to the standard vsftpd log file specified in the vsftpd_log_file directive (/var/log/vsftpd.log by default) is sent to the system logger instead under the FTPD facility.)

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli : many eyes make all bugs shallow! Nothing to worry about and i hadn't seen the implication of `syslog_enable=yes` , which makes me curious as to what takes precedence or if both occur.

Comment: I have added user 'openwrt' in /etc/vsftpd.users file as:   root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/vsftpd.users
openwrt

Comment: The log file is as follows:                                                                                                           Mon Jun  8 05:03:35 2015 [pid 1423] CONNECT: Client "192.168.1.100"
Mon Jun  8 05:03:35 2015 [pid 1422] [openwrt] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.1.100"
Mon Jun  8 05:03:43 2015 [pid 1426] CONNECT: Client "192.168.1.100"
Mon Jun  8 05:03:43 2015 [pid 1425] [openwrt] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.1.100"
Mon Jun  8 05:03:43 2015 [pid 1427] [openwrt] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "192.168.1.100", "/part1/ext_flash.txt", 0.00Kbyte/sec

Comment: In the /mnt/ folder I am mounting external usb thumb drive partition to /mnt/ folder.