# Need IPTABLES rules explanation about OpenVPN set up

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

I've got Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenVPN installed and seems to be working fine. But when I check firewall rules using "sudo ufw status", then I see this:

```
Status: active
```

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
465                        ALLOW       Anywhere
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere
110                        ALLOW       Anywhere
995                        ALLOW       Anywhere
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere
10025                      ALLOW       Anywhere
10024                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
465 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
110 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
995 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
143 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
10025 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
10024 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Port 1194 isn't mentioned at all! But I use netstat command "root@mail:~# netstat -anlp |grep 1194" I get this:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                           1142/openvpn
```

Also I have this file, created by the OpenVPN script here /etc/systemd/system/openvpn-iptables.service and I see this in it:

```
  [Unit]
Before=network.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to xx.249.16.253
ExecStart=/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
ExecStart=/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ExecStart=/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ExecStop=/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to xx.249.16.253
ExecStop=/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
ExecStop=/sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ExecStop=/sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So my question is... if port 1194 is open **(is it?)** with these IPTABLES rules, then why I don't see it in ufw status?

Comment: `ufw` shows only the ufw configuration and any rules inserted directly in your firewall configuration (with `iptables` directly or another tool such as docker) without going through ufw are NOT displayed. - also see https://serverfault.com/q/696182/37681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that the confusion is coming because you are using both UFW and IPTABLES.  UFW is a front-end for iptables, but if you add rules outside it I expect that it can't recognises those rules.

Thus you are not seeing the iptables rules injected to handle your OpenVPN connection.

I expect if you list the iptables rules you will see them. Try

```
  /sbin/iptables -vnL
```

To show the IPTables and UFW rules (but in the IPTABLES form)

Comment: And what exactly should I type in the terminal? sudo iptables -vnL? And how to incorporate /sbin/ into the command?

Comment: "sudo /sbin/iptables -vnL" should do if you are not already root

Comment: Probably this line in a very long output of that command is what you were asking for? ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194 So does it mean that port 1194 udp is open for OpenVPN outside of UFW control?

Comment: Yes, that command will allow UDP traffic on port 1194 in and out your device.   I fully expect that is outside UFW control, but I can't advise with total certainty without knowing what chain it is in.