# How do I block port 22 to prevent incoming ssh on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, nmap

I'm trying to block port 22 to disallow incoming ssh connections on a Ubuntu VM. I have issued the command:

`$> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -dport 22 -s ###.##.##.## -j DROP`

But I can still ssh into the VM.  `nmap` reports that port 22 is still open.

How do I block port 22 to prevent incoming `ssh`?

Comment: Do you need to run `sshd` at all?

Answer (score 2):

The thing to remember is that firewall rules are checked in the order they are listed. The kernel will stop processing the chain when a rule is triggered that will either allow or dis-allow a packet or connection.

I think the most common mistake for novice firewall administrators is that they follow the correct instructions to open or block a new connection, such as the one one you did
and then discover that it won't take effect.

The reason for that is that the  `-A` option adds that new rule, **after all existing rules** and you probably have a higher priority  existing rule that allows SSH.

Use -I to insert your new rules as the first in the chain and they will not be negated by existing rules, or rather , always look at your complete firewall config

See also [Debugging iptables and common firewall pitfalls?](https://serverfault.com/questions/696182/debugging-iptables-and-common-firewall-pitfalls)